# Force resize of Java window

Tags: compiz, java, metacity, window, resize

I'm trying to resize a dialog window from a Java application (Thinkorswim). Oddly, the main application window doesn't suffer from the same issue and can be minimized/maximized without a problem.

Currently, the settings dialogs for Thinkorswim are ridiculously big. Output from xwininfo shows that the window is 895x13037. There is no Minimize/Maximize buttons in the title bar.

I'm on 10.10 using Gnome with Metacity + Compiz. Dual monitors off an Nvidia 9800GT.

Things I've tried:

1. Setting window size rules in Compiz for the window type specified when you "grab" the window.
2. Force resizing using wmctrl (i.e.`$wmctrl -i -r 0x04a0373c -e 0,0,0,895,895)`
3. Alt+click and moving to the bottom of the window to resize for lowe-right corner, but there is no resize cursor.

Any other possibilities? I thought the swing toolkit just used the system's look and feel to size windows, so I'm stumped. Should I just contact the developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I just contact the developer?

Yes. If it is closed source, or you don't know java...